# Solr and play with SPDY

Tags: tomcat, solr, playback, spdy

I want to implement SPDY to my SOLR server. The solr server is mainly query by a SOLR app.

I was wondering if it's a good idea, would it work? Because I think that only chrome and firefox can use spdy for the moment. So will my play app take advantage of SPDY?

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason for using SPDY? Do you have any data indicating that HTTP is causing a bottleneck?

Comment: I want to improve the perfs !  And I think that using spdy even if I didn't notice a big bottle neck, could improve a little bit the perfs.

Comment: This is not a Solr question, but a question of which Java container/server you are using. As long as it runs .war files, Solr should run too.

Comment: @user1418079 - as Alexandre says, whatever you are looking for isn't specific to SOLR. If I were you, I would weigh in the end benefit before starting this. Academic interests are different however.

Comment: I think if you consider the internode communication in SolrCloud, then SPDY can be handy. As this internode communication is over HTTP and thus results in slower response.